# CSS calc() function doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: css, sass

I wanted to set a specific width in columns, but the calc function doesn't work. It shows error in Chrome dev tools.

[image]

Code:

```
.row {
  max-width: $grid-width;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;

  &:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: $gutter-vertical;
  }

  @include clearfix;

  [class^= "col-"] {
    background-color: orangered;
    float: left;

    &:not(:last-child) {
      margin-right: $gutter-horizontal;
    }
  }

  .col-1-of-2 {
    width: clac((100% - #{$gutter-horizontal}) / 2);
  }

  .col-1-of-3 {
    width: clac((100% - 2 * #{$gutter-horizontal}) / 3);
  }
}
```

Comment: Heres the code: .row {
    max-width: $grid-width;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 0 auto;
    &:not(:last-child) {
        margin-bottom: $gutter-vertical;
    }

    @include clearfix;

    [class^= "col-"] {
        background-color: orangered;
        float: left;

        &:not(:last-child) {
            margin-right: $gutter-horizontal;
        }
    }

    .col-1-of-2 {
        width: clac((100% - #{$gutter-horizontal}) / 2);
    }

    .col-1-of-3 {
        width: clac((100% - 2 * #{$gutter-horizontal}) / 3);
    }
}

Comment: Typo - `clac` !== `calc`.

Comment: If you don't have to support IE11 I would recommend using CSS grid, as it comes with grid-layout and gutter features all build in.

Comment: Pro tip: use real words here. Txtspk abominations like "plz" are downvote magnets - save that for social media.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you posted in the comments, has clac() instead of calc()

```
{ width: clac((100% - 2 * #{$gutter-horizontal}) / 3); } }
```

Comment: Thanks mate, such a dumb mistake.

Answer (score 1):

spelling of `calc` is wrong it's `clac` in your code

Comment: Thanks, that was a dumb mistake.